# How tosolve template does not exist on hosting on PythonAnywhere

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, pythonanywhere

I made a project and I want to host this on PythonAnywhere But if I run my application I'm having template does not exist error.

**Setting.py**

```
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-_5&ew#uj!u(kjfmo7b@nxh9=o6fg4!8t3u2a9yj*@vti2u7i^u'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['manojgupta143.pythonanywhere.com']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'Blog',
    'taggit',

]
```

this is my setting file where I fefined my setting of template

Folder structure where my template folder exists:

```
/home/manojgupta143/Blog-project-with-django/templates/blog
```

If I run web page  I'm having these types of errors

```
ImportError at /
Module "django.template.backends.django" does not define a "Django/Templates" attribute/class
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://manojgupta143.pythonanywhere.com/
Django Version: 3.2
Exception Type: ImportError
Exception Value:    
Module "django.template.backends.django" does not define a "Django/Templates" attribute/class
Exception Location: /home/manojgupta143/.virtualenvs/myproj/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py, line 22, in import_string
Python Executable:  /usr/local/bin/uwsgi
Python Version: 3.9.5
Python Path:    
['/home/manojgupta143/Blog-project-with-django/',
 '/var/www',
 '.',
 '',
 '/var/www',
 '/usr/local/lib/python39.zip',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.9',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload',
 '/home/manojgupta143/.virtualenvs/myproj/lib/python3.9/site-packages']
Server time:    Sat, 05 Feb 2022 07:59:23 +0000
```

web Page Configuration

```
Source code:
/home/manojgupta143/Blog-project-with-django/  Go to directory


Working directory:/home/manojgupta143/

WSGI configuration file:/var/www/manojgupta143_pythonanywhere_com_wsgi.py
Python version: 3.9
```

**wsgi.py**

```
# +++++++++++ DJANGO +++++++++++
# To use your own django app use code like this:
import os
import sys

#
## assuming your django settings file is at '/home/manojgupta143/mysite/mysite/settings.py'
## and your manage.py is is at '/home/manojgupta143/mysite/manage.py'
path = '/home/manojgupta143/Blog-project-with-django/'
if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.insert(0, path)

#os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE','/Blogproject.settings')


os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'Blogproject.settings'
#
## then:


from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

first when I try to run then I got the error template noy exists. Now its rendering a new error.

Comment: provide your **TEMPLATES** list from settings.py file

Comment: Please don't Write with Random Upper case Letters Like This. It's very Annoying to Read Text like That.

Comment: TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.Django/Templates',
        'DIRS': [ BASE_DIR/'templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

Comment: Your "BACKEND" is incorrect -- it should be django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates, without the slash

Comment: yep but still i having same error templates does not exist

Comment: Perhaps you could post the new error message?  If you've made that fix, the error will be different because that specific problem won't be happening.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you've define your TEMPLATES url in settings.py

```py
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        ...
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR/'templates'],
        ...
]
```

Comment: yes brother I have  defined

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, but i managed to resolved it by changing my templates in the right directory.

So add some more context, make sure that you add your templates folder on the main directory, instead of the your project folders, as you would in VS code.

**Example**
**Don't do this**

Project Name

- Template
- Project Name

  - yadayada.html

Instead, to this.

Project Name

- Templates
- yadayada.html

Give this a try and hopefully this will work.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).